# Nested Values not Displaying in Show View Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a `Roast` model, that has many `Countries` which has many `Regions`.

**I am struggling to get the countries and regions to display in my roasts show view**. I can see I have values for country_id and region_id in my Roast model so I know the values have been inserted OK.

In it's current form, it's not actually throwing any errors so I'm a little lost as to what to try next?

From the log it looks like it trying to find the country values, but I can't see regions:

```
Processing by RoastsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"belong_to"}
  Roast Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "roasts".* FROM "roasts" WHERE "roasts"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "belong_to"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Roast Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "roasts".* FROM "roasts" WHERE "roasts"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "belong_to"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Roaster Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "roasters".* FROM "roasters" WHERE "roasters"."roaster_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["roaster_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering roasts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."user_id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered partials/_mainnav.html.erb (15.6ms)
  Country Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."roast_id" = $1  [["roast_id", 76]]
  Note Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "notes".* FROM "notes" INNER JOIN "tastings" ON "notes"."id" = "tastings"."note_id" WHERE "tastings"."roast_id" = $1  [["roast_id", 76]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 76], ["commentable_type", "Roast"]]
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (3.9ms)
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roasts" WHERE "roasts"."roaster_id" = 3
  Roast Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "roasts".* FROM "roasts" WHERE "roasts"."roaster_id" = 3
  Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered roasts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (42.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 274ms (Views: 260.5ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

**models**

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tastings
  has_many :countries
  has_many :notes, through: :tastings
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries
  has_many :regions
  belongs_to :roaster

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, inverse_of: :country
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions
  belongs_to :roast

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, inverse_of: :regions
```

**roasts/show.html.erb**

```
  <tbody>
    <% @roast.countries.each do |countries| %>
    <tr>

      <th>
        <%= roast.countries.country_name %>
      </th>

      <% @roast.countries.region.each do |region| %>
       <th>
         <%= region.region_name %>
      </th>
    </tr>
<% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**roast_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @roast = Roast.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @roast
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @sameroaster = Roast.where(roaster: @roast.roaster)
    @samecountry = Roast.where(country: @roast.country)
    @roastcount = Roast.where(roaster: @roast.roaster)
    @countries = @roast.countries
    @regions = @roast.regions

  end
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "country_name"
    t.integer "region_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "roast_id"
    t.string "slug"
  end
  create_table "regions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "region_name"
    t.integer "country_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  create_table "roasts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "roaster"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "bestfor"
    t.string "beans"
    t.string "roast"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "tastingnotes"
    t.string "slug"
    t.string "avatar_file_name"
    t.string "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.integer "roaster_id"
    t.integer "country_id"
    t.boolean "decaf"
    t.boolean "coldbrew"
    t.integer "region_id"
    t.index ["country"], name: "idx_roasts_country"
    t.index ["country_id"], name: "idx_roasts_country_id"
    t.index ["roaster_id"], name: "idx_roasts_roaster_id"
```

Comment: Paste the controller code where you are querying for regions? and how exactly you want to show it on page?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy just added o the post.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question

If you want

> Roast has many countries

and

> Country has many Regions

Do the following changes

```
  create_table "roasts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "country_id" #remove country_id column from roasts
    t.integer "region_id"  #remove region_id column from roasts
    t.index ["country_id"], name: "idx_roasts_country_id" #remove
  end

  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "region_id" #remove region_id column from countries
  end
```

your model structure should be like this

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tastings
  has_many :countries
  has_many :notes, through: :tastings
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries
  #remove has_many regions for roast
  # because as per your question country has many regions not roast
  has_many :regions #remove this
  belongs_to :roaster

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, inverse_of: :country
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions
  belongs_to :roast

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, inverse_of: :regions
end
```

and controller actions and views should be something like

```
def show
      @roast = Roast.includes(countries: :regions)
                    .friendly
                    .find(params[:id])
      @commentable = @roast
      @comments = @commentable.comments
      @comment = Comment.new
      @sameroaster = Roast.where(roaster: @roast.roaster)
      @roastcount = Roast.where(roaster: @roast.roaster).count

    end
```

views

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Country</th>
       <th>Regions</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @roast.countries.each_with_index do |country, index| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
        <td><%= country.name %></td> // change this to country_name if your field is different in contries schema.
        <td><%= country.regions.map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>// change this to region_name if your field is different in regions schema.
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Narasimha.  Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue. No error mesage, but I can see in the log it's still not finding country_id
  `Country Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."roast_id" = 74`

Comment: yeah, it is as expected only. nothing wrong in it. next it should load regions. if you don't mine just update the logs in the question with recent one

Comment: For `roast_id 74, I can see in the database it has country_id=99 and region_id=81. So definitely values there.  There's obviously something wrong with the chaining, or association but can't work it out.

Comment: it difficult to anwer with out your tables schema. If you add i can look into it

Comment: added the schemas

Comment: @SimonCooper Updated answer

Comment: Thanks.  If I remove country_id from Roasts table, how can it look up the country?

Comment: You have has_many association between roast and country right? if so it will check roast_id in countries table. if any country with roast_id 74 is present it will load for you.  read more about associations here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations